# Do we get up -of / from / the- bed?

Tags: prepositions

Do we get-up **of / from / the** bed?

Examples:

> Pleaee Jon, get-up *of / from / the* bed.
>
> When he got-up *of / from / the* bed,  he saw his frriend waiting next to the door.

Comment: You'd normally just say *got out of bed*. If you really want to use *get up xxx something*, the xxx can be *out of* or *from*, as in *he got up out of the hollow he'd been hiding in*.

Comment: I have never seen *get-up* (as a verb) hyphenated before. It's normally two words—the verb and a preposition: *get up*, *get down*, *get out*, *get in*, *get through*.

Comment: Thank you for the note. I have to say that I have never seen it too. The main reason I put the hyphen is to distinguish between the preposition that I asked about to the preposition I assume it should be there anyway and the others are additional to it.

Comment: You might consider changing **of** to ***off***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note:

- John, please get up. Don't stay in bed anymore now.
- John, please **get [up] off the bed** [surface] and go sit in your chair to study.
- John, please **get out** of bed. Your friend is waiting. [**He was sleeping in his bed**]

[meaning of get up alone: when a person was sleeping or lying down. To get up means to stand up after having been lying down, in bed or on the couch etc. go to sleep/bed versus get up. What time do you get up in the morning?]

- If you are ***sitting*** on the bed, you **get up from** the bed. .
- You might sometimes see: **He got up off the bed** and went to the window. **Get up off of a bed** or couch means: to stand up after sitting or lying on the **surface** of a bed or couch. It does not imply you had been **sleeping in the bed.**
- that's because we say: he is **on the bed**, as if he were a thing. My hat is **on the bed**. So the bed is like a surface: on the bed/off the bed. The cat jumped off the bed.

Note: off implies a surface. But we even say it for some reason for a phone: Get off that phone now.